# attrib -s -r -h /s /d is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: windows, attributes, command-prompt

I just wanna ask about this problem.

I want to retrieve my files on my flash drive and then I tried this one:

```
-s -r -h /s /d
```

but the result is:

```
'-s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I solve this one ?

Comment: Do you want to use the `attrib` command?  How do you expect that will help you?

Answer (score 12):

Try changing the environment variables :-

1. Right click My Computer> Properties> Advanced System Settings.
2. In the Advanced System Settings Tab, click on **Environment variables** and look for     **Path** in **System variables**
3. Click **Edit** and add **C:\Windows\System32;** at the end of the string.**MAKE SURE YOU DON'T DELETE THE REST OF THE STRING.**

Comment: Visual cue of what to do:
https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: The root cause of the issue seems to be that when running a standalone script (i.e., not directly from a command prompt window) that the expanding registry strings aren't getting expanded (sometimes).  Replacing %WinDir% with C:\Windows in the PATH system variable seems to resolve the problem.

However, when running scripts or commands directly from a command prompt window, the PATH properly expands.  I wonder if Microsoft's new terminal isn't silently running .cmd scripts.

In HKCR\cmdfile\shell\open\command, the value is "%1" %* as opposed to directly calling cmd.exe with the /c switch.

Answer (score 0):

For a once off attrib call you can use:

```
C:\Windows\System32\attrib.exe
```

Or you can change directory first and add the path in the parameters:

```
cd C:\Windows\System32\
```

then

```
attrib.exe -s -r -h "d:\file1.txt" /s /d
```